# jQuery call to set colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-fancyproductdesigner

I want to make use of an jquery statement.

http://jquerydoc.fancyproductdesigner.com/classes/jQuery.fn.fancyProductDesigner.defaults.elementParameters.html#prop-colors

I want to set specific colors, like this ---> `Colorpicker, colors: "#000000,#ffffff"`

```
var fpd = jQuery('#fancy-product-designer-' + productID + '').data('fancy-product-designer');
    fpd.getProduct();
```

I thought this was the right way, but it isn't.

```
fpd.defaults.colors(Colorpicker, colors: "#000000,#ffffff");
```

[Link to the website](http://dev.panel-it.eu/nl/product/ontwerp-sticker-effen-kleuren)

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin?

Comment: Sure... How?

http://dev.panel-it.eu/nl/product/ontwerp-sticker-effen-kleuren/

Comment: Well, Still it's hard for me to understand what exactly you need. I prefer to see a snippet with only the widget and more specific requirement like "I have this and I need that". If I need to guess, you need to change the defaults like `fpd.defaults.colors = "#000000,#ffffff";`. Also, I can't see this code in your website. If you add this code, there are errors in the `console`?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fpd.defaults.colors="#000000,#ffffff"')

I am logging fpd to console.

Maybe now you can see more.

Elements with are added to canvas have different colors, I want to set them with the jQuery call.

Comment: I still don't understand. Now, when I'm trying to add an element, his color is black.

Comment: When you click the element you get a color range.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4258476/Schermafbeelding%202016-02-16%20om%2012.26.04.png

Comment: So you want to allow only white and black? Is that it?

Comment: I want to handle specific colors in my Php script, so different option per product type.

But for now changing the option to only black and with will help me along.

Comment: Can you unminified the files for me please?

Comment: Now I load the jquery.fancyProductDesigner.js instead of jquery.fancyProductDesigner.min.js

Is that the file you need unminified?

Comment: Now it's not working ;( By minify I meant the script in the page (which is start with `var fancyProductDesigner, $selector, $` http://i.stack.imgur.com/LLedZ.png. Just try to add the line `jQuery.fn.fancyProductDesigner.defaults.elementParameters.colors = ['#000000','#ffffff']` before the line `fancyProductDesigner = $selector.fancyProductDesigner({`

Comment: That is in the plugin file, I wan't to handle this without changing the plugin.

$.fn.fancyProductDesigner.defaults.elementParameters.colors = ['#000000','#ffffff'];

    console.log('fancyProductDesigner.defaults');
    console.log($.fn.fancyProductDesigner.defaults);
    console.log('fancyProductDesigner.defaults.elementParameters');      
    console.log($.fn.fancyProductDesigner.defaults.elementParameters);
    console.log(fancyProductDesigner);

This is what I have so far, I can set the parameters. But they aren't applied

Comment: Somehow I need to reload the designer with my own options


 jQuery.fn.fancyProductDesigner = function( options ) {

  return this.each(function() {

   var element = $(this);

            // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
            if (element.data('fancy-product-designer')) { return };

            var fpd = new FancyProductDesigner(this, options);

            // Store plugin object in this element's data
            element.data('fancy-product-designer', fpd);

  });
 };

Comment: I have no answer for in the next short time without dive deeper and I have no time for this.. Sory.. I can suggest you a hack, You can ,for now, to hide `(display:none)` the irrelevant colors.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got it...

```
$('#fancy-product-designer-' + productID + '').on('elementAdded', function(evt, obj) {
obj.params.colors = ['#000000','#ffffff', '#125634'];
});
```